# How to protect a SaaS application where the novelty is client-side?

Tags: security, saas

I am working on a SaaS project where a lot of the novelty is in client-side code/interface. (javascript/html5/canvas)

How would I prevent people from simply copying my product?

This application will offer 'embeddable' code (like youtube) so people can share it on other sites.

I've thought about simple code obfuscation, but what other options do I have?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If it's "embeddable... like youtube" it still has to hit your server to be useful. At any rate: no one wants to steal your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that if you are successful people will copy your product anyway (Great problem to have BTW). The technology doesn't matter. It could be node or ruby or smalltalk, it's the functionality that people want. Creating a great product and continuing to innovate will keep these copycats at bay.

Brandon